# Socket Exceptions for no network hops

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, tomcat, networking

We have a Tomcat server that is in one case, responding to a web service and in another attempting to call a web service.  In both cases the caller and end point are running on the local box.  Yet there is a connection being lost and we know that it is not a network appliance.

Here are part of the exceptions:

The response:

```
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at org.apache.x.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:364)
        at org.apache.x.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:326)
        at org.apache.x.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:571)
```

And the call:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://localhost:7720/x/xService: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

The particulars:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Server number:  7.0.40.0
OS Name:        Windows Server 2008 R2
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   x86
JVM Version:    1.7.0_25-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

I should add that the server, once these errors occur, does not recover gracefully.  It has to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Well,since the whole log is not present the best guess I have is that either your port(7720) or url is incorrect or blocked locally (i.e being used by some other application) or the localhost entry in the hosts file is overridden and changed to something else instead of 127.0.0.1